# Bootstrap's override custom color won't apply

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am trying to add a theme color on Bootstrap's theme colors map but it wasn't working.

I am following this [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCX3QVl_PiI&t=307s). And [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/customize/sass/#modify-map).

And it still doesn't work, I don't see any errors to my code.

```
@import "../functions";
@import "../variables";

$custom-colors: (
    "dark-primary": hsl(255, 11%, 22%)
);

// Merge the maps
$theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, $custom-colors);

//bootstrap import
@import "../bootstrap.scss";
```

Comment: This is probably a minor thing, but shouldn't `map-merge` be `map.merge`, instead?

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do, is create my custom class for the element and just override it with `!important.`

```
.myElement{
  color: #000 !important;
}
```

Just make sure to override the correct property. Google Chrome Developer Tools might help.